# What isolation level exist between Azure deployment slots?

Tags: azure, deployment, slots

It would like to know how Azure handles isolation for Web App deployment slots? For example if I have production and staging deployment slots on the same instance (a pattern that I've seen recommended many times in articles), what happens if my  staging slot has a memory leak or is misbehaving consuming a lot of resources, will it's resource consumption on CPU/memory impact other slots deployed on the same instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each deployment slot runs on the same App Service instance so if one behaves badly or you're doing load testing on one, the other ones will be impacted.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected.